# How to update view inside the viewpager2 that attach to fragment on fragment onResume?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I have a fragment "Fragment List" that contains `Viewpager2`.

When user clicks a button "Fragment List" will be replaced with "Fragment Form", after user finish updating the form. I will pop backstack the "Fragment Form". And the `OnResume` of "Fragment List" will be called

**The problem is**, NONE of the viewpager's fragment lifecycle gets called then how to tell the viewpager's fragment to update the data when "Fragment List" `OnResume` get called?

**Please note** that using interface may produce `NullPointerException` because when "Fragment List" `OnResume` get called, the `viewpager` may not ready yet

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current page fragment of the `ViewPager` in the `Fragment List` fragment, and call a method directly on it to do your changes.

I assume that your `ViewPager` page fragment is named as `PageFragment`

add below in `onResume()` of the `Fragment List` fragment when you come back from `Fragment Form`

```
PageFragment fragment = (PageFragment) 
          mViewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
fragment.someMethod();  // pass your parameters
```

Create `someMethod()` method in the `PageFragment`, and pass it the parameters that you want to change there.

You also need to handle whether the `onResume()` of the `Fragment List` fragment gets called due to coming back from the `Fragment Form` or something else.

**UPDATE**

> `instantiateItem` is not available. I am using Viewpager2, and `ViewPagerAdapter` which extends `FragmentStateAdapter`

You're right the above code works for `ViewPager`, and for `ViewPager2` You can get the fragment of the current page with:

```
PagerFragment fragment = (PagerFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager()
                           .findFragmentByTag("f" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

then you can call some method on it.

```
fragment.someMethod();  // pass your parameters
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But what is instantiateItem? Cause instantiateItem is not available. I am using Viewpager2, and ViewPagerAdapter which extends FragmentStateAdapter

Comment: @Hal.ss thanks for the comment.. sorry for that I updated the answer in *UPDATE* section according to `ViewPager2`